# nested loop to split strings inside array in a batch file

Tags: loops, batch-file, split

i have an array and a variable

```
SET users=nick_derus peter_parker john_simpsons cool_guy
set mid=freak
```

i need to create files named like the following:

```
"derus freak nick"
"parker freak peter"
"simpsons freak john"
"freak guy cool"
```

and i'm failing over and over again. any help on how to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I cannot see any nested loops in your "code"...

Comment: Just a comment: the `SET users=nick_derus peter_parker john_simpsons cool_guy` variable is _not_ an [array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type), but a _list_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As they are unlikely file names, you'll have to determine the command you want to run yourself and change line five accordingly:

```
@Echo Off
Set users=nick_derus peter_parker john_simpsons cool_guy
Set mid=freak
For %%a In (%users%) Do For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=_" %%b In ("%%a") Do (
    Echo createfile "%%c %mid% %%b")
pause
```

This ignores the fact your last example name doesn't follow the format of the others.

Comment: Thanks a lot, last example was a mistake. It works great and it was much easier than what i was trying